# Resampling multiple images in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro

I'm  to resampling about 30 raster images to different resolution (2, 3, 4, 5 meters) using the ArcPy. I wrote the code but its giving result for one image.
Here is the code:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/test/input/Year2020/multispectral"
rasters =arcpy.ListRasters ("*", "TIF")
ab= r"C:\Users/test/input/year2020/multispectral"
ab_raster= os.path.join (output_folder, "a.tif")
arcpy.management.Resample(in_raster=raster, out_raster=ab,cell_size="10 10",resampling_type="CUBIC")
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to resample each raster to 2, 3, 4, 5 meters?

Use a for loop with range:

```
import arcpy, os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\Rasters\Folder1"
out_folder = r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\Rasters\Folder2"

for r in arcpy.ListRasters ("*", "TIF"):
    for resolution in range(2, 6):
        out_raster = os.path.join(out_folder, r.replace('.tif','_cellsize_{0}m.tif'.format(resolution)))
        arcpy.Resample_management(in_raster=r, out_raster=out_raster, cell_size=str(resolution), resampling_type="CUBIC")
```

Comment: thanks so much  it worked but it didnt work for decimals resampling e.g 05 by 0.5